# Pass parameter from MVC view to an action using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following code which currently does as expected in that the destination view is loaded. This is called when a user hits enter in the input field. This is part of a .net core/C# web project.

```
    <script>
    function keypresshandle(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var url = "@Url.Action("Selection", "Home")";
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

However I also want to pass the value of the input field to the view as well. Can anyone tell me how please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass query parameters (value for your action), you will have to use something like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Selection", "Home", new { value = "inputValue" })';
```

It will generate following url: `/Selection/Home?value=inputValue`

Comment: Hi, so here us my updated script but now this is not reaching public IActionResult Selection(string value), any ideas please?

var url = "@Url.Action("Selection", "Home", new { value = " + SearchTxt.value + " })";

Answer (score 0):

In js , if you want to pass the value you entered dynamically, you can write like this:

```
   var url = "@Url.Action("Selection", "Home")?value=" + $(this).val();
    window.location.href = url;
```

Here `value` is the parameter name ,which should `be the same as the receive parameter` in Selection action.

```
public IActionResult Selection(string value)
{
    // do what you want.
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi, so here is my updated line, this no longer reaches public IActionResult Selection(string value), any ideas please?


var url = "@Url.Action("Selection", "Home")?value=" + SearchTxt.value;

Comment: @Kev, Can you tell us what `SearchTxt` here represents? Please give us more of your code for reference, or you can use `F12` to debug the code and confirm whether `SearchTxt.value` gets the input's value. If you want to get the value of the input box, you can use my jQuery method, or refer to this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: Hi @Yongqing Yu, SearchTxt is a input textbox. I have confirmed the value is correct by showing it in an alert popup - Kec

Comment: @Kev, if so,please check whether the console option of F12 prompts any error message? And provide your controller code to us for reference to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your route is like this

```
"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

If so, try this one.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Selection", "Home", new { id = "inputValue" })';
```